# Rails API, JavaScript on Raspberry PI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

This may be a very specific question, but I do not know how to find the answer for some time now.

I am currently developing an app which would stand on the **Raspberry PI** machine, would work only **locally**. I have wrote an **API** in Ruby on Rails to serve the db and have used jQuery to call **REST** requests. On my computer it works how it should, however, on the RPI server seems to not receive any requests. When I **POST** an request it stops as **OPTIONS**, with continous loading.

I have checked all the gems which are working on my computer and installed them on RPI.

I am using putty to connect to the RPI.

Not sure where the problem may lie, any suggestions would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I figured out that I've set AJAX method to send to localhost - I am not sure how to set the pages to communicate with API on the RPI, not on my computer.

So the question now is:

Is there any way to easily add existing app (html, js, css) to be served by the Rails API?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there logging in the app on the RPI?

Comment: No... But I figured out that I've set AJAX method to send to localhost - I am not sure how to set the pages to communicate with API on the RPI, not on my computer.